# how to guaranty orderly start/stop of multiple integration-flows

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

let's say that my application has the 2 following flows:

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> LocalDateTime.now(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))))
                .channel("DIRECT_CHANNEL")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("DIRECT_CHANNEL")
                .handle(lateToStartOutboundAdapter)
                .get();
    }
```

How do I guaranty that flow1 doesn't start sending messages before all components in flow2 are ready ?
More generally, how can I orderly start my integration-flows ?

My current way to do it, is as follows:
1) I define a controlBus Integration-flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("CONTROL_CHANNEL").controlBus().get();
}
```

2) I set the first endpoint component in all the other integration-flows to autoStart=false:

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> LocalDateTime.now(),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                            .autoStartup(false)
                            .id("flow1Component"))
                .transform(p -> p)
                .channel("DIRECT_CHANNEL")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("DIRECT_CHANNEL")
                .transform(p -> p,
                        c -> c.autoStartup(false)
                              .id("flow2Component"))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> m.toString())
                .get();
    }
```

3) finally I define a Server component where I start all my flows through the control-bus:

```
@Component
public class Server implements SmartLifecycle　｛

    private boolean running;
    List<String> flowComponents = ImmutableList.of("flow2Component","flow1Component")

    ＠Autowired
    @Qualifier("CONTROL_CHANNEL")
    private MessageChannel controlChannel;

    public void start() {
        flowComponents.forEach(s -> 
            controlChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("@" + s + ".start()").build());
        running = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        flowComponents.reverse().forEach(s -> 
            controlChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("@" + s + ".stop()").build());
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
```

Is above a valid way to orderly start/stop my integration-flows ?
Thank you very much in advance for your expertise.
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to set `autoStartup` to `false` on a consumer from a `DirectChannel`; such components are not "active". All that `start()` does there is subscribe the consumer to the channel.

You only need to set it on the poller, and start that one when you are ready.